# Building an application + JSON API in Laravel

Tags: php, json, rest, laravel, client

I'm planning to build a web application in Laravel. So far so good, but it needs a JSON RESTful API as well.

What's the best way to go about this? Should I build a separate Laravel API and Laravel client, or is it better to have one application with both JSON and HTML representations?

There are probably benefits to gain from separating the two, although I can't really see them at this point. The downsides are obvious however, having to maintain two code bases and having to implement REST consuming functionality in the client.

Any other options out there? Pros and cons?

Answer (score 1):

Namespace everything. You can keep it all inside the same application then. There is no point in maintaining 2 code bases because you will have to repeat your business logic in 2 places.

In your routes, then you can then do this

```
Route::controller('user', 'UserController');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'namespace' => 'Api'], function() {
    Route::controller('user', 'Api\UserController');
});
```

Also, don't write your business logic in your controllers. Use commands (known as jobs in Laravel 5.1) and [repositories](http://culttt.com/2013/07/08/creating-flexible-controllers-in-laravel-4-using-repositories/) instead.

Pretend you have a *Create User* feature. Then you will have a corresponding Command/Job class for that.

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class CreateUser extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function handle(Mailer $mailer)
    {
        // logic to create user
    }
}
```

Which you will use in your `UserController`

```
public function postCreateUser()
{
    // validate request

    $this->dispatch(new CreateUser($inputData));

    // return view
}
```

and then your `Api\UserController`

```
public function postCreateUser()
{
    // validate request

    $this->dispatch(new CreateUser($inputData));

    // return JSON output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would chose separation. I like to approach like this:

```
//routes.php
Route::group([], function()
{
    Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/', ['as' => 'homepage', 'uses' => 'SiteController@index']);
    //other frontend routes
});

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'], function()
{
    Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/admin', ['as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'SiteController@index']);
    //other admin/backend routes
});

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Rest'], function()
{
    Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/rest', ['as' => 'rest', 'uses' => 'RestController@index']);
    //other rest routes
});
```

Controllers for frontend in Controllers folder.
Controllers for admin in Controllers/Admin folder.
Controllers for rest in Controllers/Rest folder.